# How to find an object inside an array inside a mongoose model?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to query an object that's inside an item which is inside a mongoose model, when I'm trying to find that object with the `find()` method or `_.find()` method, I can't get access to the object for some reason and when I `console.log()` it, it gives me `undefined` or when I use `array.filter()` it gives me an empty array, which means the object that I'm trying to access does not meet the criteria that I give it in the lodash find method, but then when I look at my database I see that the object does actually have the properties to meet the criteria. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong, here's my code: as you can see I'm trying to get the information of the item that the user clicked on and want to see:

```
router.get("/:category/:itemId", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.itemId);
    //gives the item id that the user clicked on
    console.log(req.params.category);
    //gives the name of category so I can find items inside it
    Category.findOne({ name: req.params.category }, (err, category) => {
      const items = category.items; //the array of items
      console.log(items); //gives an array back
      const item = _.find(items, { _id: req.params.itemId });
      console.log(item); //gives the value of 'undefined' for whatever reason
    });
  });
```

The category Schema:

```
const catSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    default: "Unlisted",
  },
  items: [
    {
      name: String,
      price: Number,
      description: String,
      img: String,
      dateAdded: Date,
      lastUpdated: Date,
    },
  ],
  dateCreated: Date,
  lastUpdate: Date,
});
```

Comment: Elements in the `items` array don't appear to have an `_id` field. What does logging `items` give you?

Comment: mongoose automatically creates ```_id``` field for each item, and I can see that field in the database, loggin items gives me all the objects that's inside the items array(including ```_id``` for each object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the answer is a little bit obvious, you are using MongoDB and in Mongo you have "_ID" you can use that "_ID" only with Mongoose! so you just have to remove the underscore and that is it! do it like this `const item = _.find(items, { id: req.params.itemId });`

Answer (score 1):

hope you are doing better.
When I look at your `Schema` I see that the item field is an array of objects which doesn't have an `_id` inside so when you create a new instance of `catShema` it just generates an `_id` field for the new instance but not for each item inside the `items` array, just also enter the id of the item in question because according to my understanding, you must also have a model called `items` in your database
When you save these records in your database, you will generate an element with this structure

```
{
    _id: String, // auto generated
    name: String,
    items: [ {"name1", "price1", "description1", "imgUrl1", "dateAdded1", "lastUpdated1"},{"name2", "price2", "description2", "imgUrl2", "dateAdded1", "lastUpdated2"}, ...],
    dateCreated: Date,
    lastUpdate: Date
}
```

**Note : the code provided at the top is only an illustration of the object which will be registered in the database and not a valid code**

Here you can notice that there is not a field called `_id` in the object sent inside the database.
**My suggestion to solve this issue is**

- To create an additional field inside the `items` array called `_id` like :

  {
  ...,
  items: [
  {
  _id: {
  type: String,
  unique : true,
  required: true // to make sure you will always have it when you create a new instance
  },
  ...
  ... // the rest of fields of items
  },
  ...

Now when you create a new instance make sure in the object you enter in the database the `_id` is recorded when you call the `catInstance.save()` so inside the `catInstance` object you have to add the current Id of the element to be able to filter using this field.
Hope my answer helped, if you have any additional questions, please let me know
Happy coding ...